# Нахождение произведения цифр вещественного числа

Tags: c++, c

*В одномерном массиве, состоящем из n вещественных элементов, найти номер максимального по модулю элемента массива произведение цифр которого кратно 4.**

В целом задача понятно и легко решалась, если бы массив состоял из целых чисел. **А вот как найти произведение цифр вещественного числа не совсем ясно.**

Comment: Может быть, надо читать как "произведение цифр индекса которого кратно четрыем"? Индексы - они хотя бы целые...

Comment: Считывайте числа как строки и работайте с символами.

Comment: Вопрос не как найти, а как ограничить длину представления этого вещественного числа... когда остановиться... К @КириллМалышев - и до какой точности преобразовывать в строку?

Comment: @Harry, имел в виду для случая, когда числа вводятся с клавиатуры

Comment: найти произведение цифр вещестенного числа так же просто, как и произведение цифр целого числа. С числами вроде 1/3 или √2 такое, разумеется, не пройдет, но исходя из формулировки задачи, там таких чисел быть не должно.

Comment: Не могли бы подсказать алгоритм нахождения произведение цифр вещественного числа? @Эникейщик

Comment: Точно такой же, как алгоритм нахождения произведения двух однозначных чисел.